# How to add data- attribute to <body> tag

Tags: filters, page-attributes

I need to add a data- attribute with a user-supplied value (via custom fields) to the  tag of each page. I tried editing header.php as such

```
<body <?php astra_schema_body(); ?> <?php bene_body_class(); ?> data-myAttr="<?php get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'my_attr')[0] ?>">
```

but when I load the page, the attribute does not show up. I'm guessing something the theme strips out all unknown attributes?

Is there a filter I can use to add it in via functions.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this. The first one is what you are trying, but you have to print out the value you get. Like this:

```
print get_post_meta();
```

I don't recommend this for two reasons:

1. You should keep your templates as simple as possible. Otherwise they become cluttered with fragments of business code which makes everything harder to maintain.
2. Printing this value requires a bit more work than you might think. Moving this to a separate place keeps your template clean and your code more readable.

Write your `body` tag like this instead:

```
<body 
    <?php 
    do_action( 'body_start_tag_attributes' ); 
    astra_schema_body(); 
    bene_body_class(); 
    ?>
>
```

Note the `do_action()` I introduced. This allows you to add any code you need from anywhere. Now let's use that hook in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'body_start_tag_attributes', function() {
    
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        return; // an archive or a 404
    }
    
    $post = get_post();
    // the last parameter means you get the first entry of the meta array.
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_attr', true );
    
    if ( ! $meta ) {
        return; // no meta value
    }
    
    $value = esc_attr( $meta );
    
    print ' data-myAttr="' . $value . '"';
});
```

As you can see, you need some "guards" before you can print the value: check for the type of the current page (singular), the presence of the attribute, and finally escape the value for security reasons.

And then, and only then, you can print it.

You can even reuse the hook to add other attributes in case you need them later — without any further changes to your template!

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. unfortunately, nothing from that callback actually ends up in the `body` tag. Would the theme possibly be stripping it out?

Comment: @Daveh0 Unlikely. Debug the problem, print out the meta value you get (maybe it's empty), check upper/lowercase and so on.

Comment: this is very strange. It seems to be taking that attribute (or whatever I output from the function), creating a `<br>` element just below `<body>` and adding the attribute there: `<br style="display:none" data-myattr="my value">. ever seen that before?

Comment: @Daveh0 Is that from View Source or from Inspect Element?

Comment: from inspect - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR8bv.png

Comment: @Daveh0 Looks like something is using that to insert the Google tag manager with a very dirty hack. Put the `do_action()` at the top of the three function calls, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: YES! that worked. GTM stuff is from this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/... just FYI. Pretty sure I'm good go now - thanks for sticking with.

Comment: This might be beyond the scope of this question or even this SE board, but for some reason, this solution only works for pages created with Elementor's standard page template. The attribute is not added when using the Elementor Canvas template. I had to use the answer posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003495/wordpress-how-to-add-attribute-to-body in order to have the attribute display on *ALL* pages. IS that the dirty hack you were referring to?

Comment: @Daveh0 Yes, using the body_class filter for anything but class names is a dirty hack. It will break as you have seen already. :)

Comment: fuxia - any suggestions for getting the printed value of `body_start_tag_attributes()` to show up in pages/posts that use anything other than the standard template?

Comment: @Daveh0 Well you have to edit the other templates as well.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having... there are no other template files. Everything uses the default header.php. If I add `data-foo="bar"` to the `<body>` tag in header.php, it displays in the Post (as opposed to page), but for some reason the value of `body_start_tag_attributes()` does not.

Comment: Just found this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-contents-to-body-tag/. Seems it was a theme-specific thing. All working normally now. This answer still stands as correct answer for non-theme-specific situation.